# Laravel :How make correct redirect to after login in multiauth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I have a problem in multi-auth in laravel

I make route

```
/admin/login
```

and I need just admin login in this route and redirect to `/admin` and if user login in it I will redirect to `/home` and make msg you can not access to this link because of your user, not admin

The problem when I login to `/admin/login` redirect to `/home` as the user but I need to be redirected `/admin`

knowing the admin and user same table in the database(user) exit col boolean `isAdmin (1 for admin and 0 for user)`

KNOWING I make `Auth\AdminLoginController` exit:

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

 public function Loginadmin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
          if (Auth::guard('admin')->Where("isAdmin" , 1)->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'isAdmin' => 1], $request->get('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

Comment: Please see this solution https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-check-user-type-and-redirect-based-on-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a Middleware. Your rout is written in this way.

```
Route::get('Dashboard', 'admin\DashboardController@index')->middleware('adminUser');
```

Or write it in the constructor function

[Learn to build Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware)

Its structure

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
class adminUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::check())
      {
        $userm = auth()->user();
        if($userm->isadmin!=1)
        {
          return redirect('');
        }
        return $next($request);
      }
      else
        return redirect('');
    }
}
```

You must create a value to determine the level of access in the user table

Comment: Thanks you 
Best regards